# Insert/remove the same element in heap sort

Tags: data-structures, heap, heapsort

Show the heap at each stage when the following numbers are inserted to an initially empty min-heap in the given order: `{11, 17, 13, 4, 4, 1 }`. Now, show the heap at each stage when we successively perform the deleteMin operation on the heap until it is empty.

Here is the answer/checkpoint I receive:

```
![1]https://imgur.com/zu47RIF
```

I have 2 questions please:

1. I don't understand when we insert element `4` the second time, why do we shift `11` to make it the right child of the old element/firstly inserted element `4`? Is it because we want to satisfy a requirement of the complete binary tree, which is each node in the levels from `1` to `k - 2` has exactly 2 children (k = levels of the trees, level k is the bottom-most level)?
2. I don't understand how we `deleteMin = 1`, `13` becomes the right child of the newly parent `11` (which is the left child of `4`). Just a quick note that my instructor gave the class 2 ways to deleteMin. The other way is fine with me - it's just the reversed process of inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Like you said, the heap shape is an "almost complete tree": all levels are complete, except the lowest level which can be incomplete to the right. Therefore, the second `4` is necessarily added to the right of `17` to preserve the heap shape:

```
        4
      /   \
    11     13
  /    \
17      4
```

After that, `4` switches places with `11` to regain the min-heap property.

2. Deletions are typically implemented by removing the root and putting the last (i.e., bottom-rightmost) element in its place. This preserves the heap shape. The new root is then allowed to sift down in order to regain the min-heap property. So `13` becomes the new root:

```
        13
      /    \
    4       4
  /   \
17     11
```

Then `13` switches places with either child node. It looks like they chose the right-hand child in your example.